# Use the latest android Data Binding library with data in a SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, mvvm, orm

In my application I'm currently using android content providers to get data from a sqlite database. That data is not shared with other apps.

Now I'd like to reengineer my app in such a way that it adopts the MVVM guidelines, but I couldn't find any best practice to use data from DBs.

Should I use an ORM like greenDAO or is there any alternative that uses data from cursors?